# dictionary transformation

Tags: python, dictionary

How to map the elements of the lists in the dictionary below to their basic keys (i.e. basic keys are the ones that map to empty lists)

```
{
'1':[],
'2':[],
'3':['1','2'],
'4':[],
'5':[],
'6':['4','5'],
'7':['3','6']
}
```

which would result in

```
{
'1':[],
'2':[],
'3':{'1':[],'2':[]},
'4':[],
'5':[],
'6':{'4':[],'5':[]},
'7':{'3':{'1':[],'2':[]},'6':{'4':[],'5':[]}}
}
```

I think it can be accomplished using a recursive function.

Comment: Please share your code and error if any.

Comment: I think it probably could be accomplished that way too. Let's do it! You start.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After `d['1'].append(42)`, is `d['3']` supposed to be `{'1': [], '2': []}` or `{'1': [42], '2': []}`?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started I would suggest something along this line.

```
def recursiveChange(object):
    if type(object) == type({}):
        #Whats happens when its a dictionary
        recursiveChange(NEWOBJECT)
    if type(object) == type([]):
        #What happens when its a list
        recursiveChange(NEWOBJECT)
```

Each time the function is called it will check what type of object it is, then changing the values as needed. With this you should be able to get an idea of the route you want to take, give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that you want to convert values like `['1', '2']` to `dict` like `{'1': [], '2': []}`.

Don't know why:

```
'6':['4','5'],
'7':['3','6']
```

Gives:

```
'6':{'4':[],'5':[]},
'7':{'3':{'1':[],'2':[]},'6':{'4':[],'5':[]}}
```

But not:

```
'6':{'4':[],'5':[]},
'7':{'3': [], '6': []}
```

?

Recursion is not necessary, but you can use a dictionary in comprehension:

```
import pprint

a = {
'1':[],
'2':[],
'3':['1','2'],
'4':[],
'5':[],
'6':['4','5'],
'7':['3','6']
}

b = {k: {i: [] for i in v} for k, v in a.items()}

pprint.pprint(b)
```

You'll get:

```
{'1': {},
 '2': {},
 '3': {'1': [], '2': []},
 '4': {},
 '5': {},
 '6': {'4': [], '5': []},
 '7': {'3': [], '6': []}}
```

Comment: That's not even close to the desired result.